# open a uiviewcontroller from uialertview button

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, uialertview

I want to open a UIViewController if a UIALertView Button is pressed.

I have the code for that. However, the uiviewcontroller is not being opened :(

I am sure the uialertview is working fine and all. and the code for the uiviewcontroller is fine as well. (it works when called from other places).

Any help ?

Thanks.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex == 0) //Yes, Sign Me Up!
{
    NSLog(@"0");
    ViewerWebController *web = [[ViewerWebController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.funimation.com/"]];
    [web setShowToolbar:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:web animated:YES];
    [web release];

}
else if (buttonIndex == 1) //Remove from List
{
    NSLog(@"1");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:false forKey:@"subscribeButtonOption"];
    [_tableView reloadData];
}
else if (buttonIndex == 2) //"Maybe Later" 
{
    NSLog(@"2");
}
}
```

Comment: Clearly some part is not working fine :)  Please post the code.

Comment: Are you pushing the view controller on to a navigation controller or displaying the view controller modally?

Comment: What are you using to "open" the UIViewController? It is hard to say what is wrong without seeing some code snippets.

Comment: Can you check if the navigation controller is initialized at the time you are trying to push it? NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController);

Answer (score 1):

This may work..

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
  // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
  if (buttonIndex == 0)
  {
      YourRootNavigationController *navController = [YourRootNavigationController sharedInstance]; // singleton
      [navController pushViewController:YOUR_CONTROLLER animated:YES];
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog(@"cancel");
  }
}
```

Comment: I want the view controller to be part of the navigation controller stack. won't that be possible ?

Answer (score 1):

The alert view doesn't have a navigation controller. You would need to keep a reference to the navigation controller you want to push the view controller on to.

Comment: how do i do that ? any hints ?

Comment: Add    `NSLog(@" nav controller is %@", self.navigationController);`  right above your call to pushViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`didDismissWithButtonIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView%3adidDismissWithButtonIndex%3a) rather [`clickedButtonAtIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView%3aclickedButtonAtIndex%3a).

The former is invoked *after* the UIAlertView has been removed from the screen hierarchy, while the latter occurs while the **UIAlertView is still on screen**. While on screen, UIAlertView alters the nature of the app; that means bad things happen when trying to push views to the nav controller.

This misuse of `clickedButtonAtIndex` seems to be common misinformation floating around the internet and StackOverflow. Cost me hours of frustration.